# C++/CUDA weird behavior with large arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm, cuda, large-data

I try to implement some sort of an Jacobi Algorithm and measure the time taken for different grid sizes.

For having the same amount of Iterations, regardless, how large the grid is, I don't use some sort of residuum, but let the Algorithm run 4000 Iterations always (but with different size of the arrays).
That works exactly as it should, until the point I exceed a 510x510 grid (double). 510x510 takes about 2763498 microseconds and then 520x520 takes 1778 microseconds.

I already tried to change from double to float arrays, to make sure it's not some kind of memory shortage, but I can't figure out, where my problem really is hidden.

```
__global__ void Jacobi(double *a, double *b, double *c, int L){
int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

if(row > 0 && col > 0 && row < L-1 && col < L-1){
    a[row * L + col] = 1.0/4.0 * (b[col+1 + row*L] + b[col - 1 + row*L] + b[col + (row+1)*L] + b[col + (row-1)*L] - c[col + row*L]);
    __syncthreads();
    b[row*L + col] = a[row*L+col];
    }
}

int main(){
int L;
int Iterations;
double *h_phi1;
double *h_phi2;

double *h_f;
FILE * temp = fopen("Timings.out", "w");
for (L=10;L<10000;L+=10){
    long long int size = L*L*sizeof(double);
    h_f = (double*) malloc(size);
    h_phi1 = (double*) malloc(size);
    h_phi2 = (double*) malloc(size);


    for(int i=0;i<L;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<L;j++){
            h_f[j+i*L] = (pow(1.0/float(L),2.0))*exp(-100.0*(pow((float(i)/float(L) - float(1.0/3.0) ),2.0) + pow(( float(j)/float(L) - float(1.0/3.0) ),2.0))) - 
            (pow(1.0/ float(L),2.0))*exp(- 100.0*(pow(( float(i)/ float(L) -(1.0- 1.0/3.0)),2.0) + pow(( float(j)/float(L)-(1.0-float(1.0/3.0))),2.0)));
            h_phi1[j+i*L] = 0;
            h_phi2[j+i*L] = 0;
        }
    }

    //allocate memory on GPU
    double *d_phi1;
    cudaMalloc(&d_phi1, size);
    double *d_phi2;
    cudaMalloc(&d_phi2, size);
    double *d_f;
    cudaMalloc(&d_f, size);
    
    //set CTA
    int threads = 16;
    int blocks = (L+threads-1)/threads;
    double epsCalc;

    //Setup Kernel launch parameters
    dim3 dimBlock(threads, threads);
    dim3 dimGrid(blocks, blocks);

    //Setup timing and Cpy Memory from Host to Device
    Iterations = 0;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cudaMemcpy(d_phi2, h_phi2, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_f, h_f, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_phi1, h_phi2, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Launch Kernel
    for (int j=0;j<4000;j++){
        Iterations += 1;
        Jacobi<<<dimBlock, dimGrid>>>(d_phi2,d_phi1,d_f,L);

    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    
    fprintf(temp, "%lf % %d \n", L, duration);
    printf("I reached the end of Jacobi after %d Iterations!\n Time taken was %d in milliseconds", Iterations, duration);
    cudaFree(d_f); cudaFree(d_phi2), cudaFree(d_phi1);
    free(h_f); free(h_phi2); free(h_phi1);
}

return 0;
}
```

I hope, somebody can guide me to where my mistake is made.

Comment: If you are concerned whether it is a memory issue, you really should be testing if `malloc` returns 0.

Comment: The time measurement in your code is broken.

Comment: I don't think, that time measurement is broken. The execution is really much faster..and the time for Iterations from (520,530....) do increase again.
Cuda-Memcheck leads to """Program hit cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration (error 9) due to "invalid configuration argument" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunchKernel. """" at 520. After that it runs again, without problems. I don't get it

Comment: There was mistakenly written milliseconds instead of microseconds. Sorry @molbdnilo

Comment: This is not correct: `Jacobi<<<dimBlock, dimGrid>>>` it should be: `Jacobi<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>`

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem. @Robert Crovella

Comment: I'm also of the opinion that your timing measurement is broken, and furthermore you might want to understand the nature of *asynchronous* kernel launches, because this also affects your timing measurement.  According to my testing you have at least 2 separate issue with your timing measurement. I understand you probably disagree; do as you wish.

Comment: If there are problems, of course I want to see them. Would you please help me with that?
I'm not that good in C languages.

Comment: You only measure the time for all the kernels to be queued to launch, not their execution time. Take 10 seconds to search, there must be 100 questions where people who don't understand that kernels are asynchronous with respect to the host get their timing wrong. Beginner mistake 101....

Comment: ah, tokay. That was, why I had a Memcpy after the for loop with the kernel call in the first place and then thought it was just there for debugging, to check the calculated function is correct and then erased it. Thank you! I will insert a cudaDeviceSynchronize(); after the for loop, that should fix it, I guess

Comment: So presumably this was a timing bug and your problem is solved? If so please consider either deleting the question or adding your own answer. It is perfectly fine to answer your own questions here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CUDA, when specifying the [kernel execution configuration arguments](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration), the grid configuration comes first, followed by the block configuration.

Therefore, given the definition and usage of the variables `dimGrid` and `dimBlock`,  this is incorrect:

```
    Jacobi<<<dimBlock, dimGrid>>>
```

it should be:

```
    Jacobi<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>
```

The grid and block configuration variables have different limits, so as it happens the first launch failure that occurred due to the mixup violating a hardware limit occurred at problem dimensions of 520,520